# Is @use and @forward supported with node-sass

Tags: npm, sass, node-sass

Are the at-rules @use and @forward supported with the current version of node-sass (6.0.1)?

I tried it in a project and it compiles but the at-rules are basically just copied to the CSS output and not resolved.

main.scss:

```
@use 'buttons';
```

main.css:

```
@use 'buttons';
```

What the main.css should look like?

```
.button {
  padding: 1rem;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: .875rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, those are only supported in dart-sass, not node-sass/libsass